# Help with Barycentric points in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am using the following code straight from the manual and it doesn't compile, with the error 'shape B is not known'. Can anybody tell me the silly mistake I must be making, as it is out of the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
       \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[2,3](30:4){B}
       \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=2)
       \tkzGetPoint{G}
       \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
       \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,G)
       \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,G)

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to delete the space after the comma and before B=2 in the command `\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1, B=2)`. It seems that you added accidentally the space because there is not in the manual.

Comment: Thanks couldn't see the extra space.